# Zuul on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to find out if Spring Cloud Zuul is working on GCP or not. If that's the case, should we use it the same way we do in AWS?
(The Services are deployed as App Engines)
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As [Zuul](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_zuul_proxy_server_and_routing.htm) is an edge server as a [bastion host](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#bastion) it should have no problem working on GCP. The dataflow and architecture will depend entirely on the GCP API and service where you will be deploying Spring Cloud, in your case (App Engine API), the management and configurations come from [Cloud VPC API features](https://cloud.google.com/vpc#section-6) such as Routes   and Load Balancer API's that will be working with Zuul.

[Here is a guide](https://programmaticponderings.com/tag/spring-boot/) explaining how to deploy it on GKE as a containerized service where they follow the integration for Zuul with Istio at service layer scope.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I took a look at the guide. It seems like suggesting to use Istio INSTEAD of Zuul. I quote:

"Kubernetes and Istio 1.0 will replace Netflix’s Zuul and  Eureka for API management, load-balancing, routing, and service discovery." 

What I'm looking for is to use Zuul and Eureka. Also, is it mandatory to use Kubernetes?

Comment: Hello Lori, That guide indeed is just for GKE and was just an example that it can be implemented, even if on GCP side the management will be through Istio the GUI and configuration could be made over Zuul. If you are using App Engine API, you will need to think and see your architecture to play nice with Cloud VPC, bus as Zuul is an edge server it surely could be implemented.